# Newly built, very high-spec PC, encountering errors and performance issues

Tags: windows-8.1, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

Since building my new PC, it’s been having a load of hard-to-trace issues. However as all the components are pretty much new, I can’t really pinpoint the cause. It’s a fresh install of Windows 8.1, and everything else is brand spanking new with up to date drivers.

It seems to be taking a while to boot up. This can vary from 20 seconds to 40 seconds and considering the spec; that’s pretty darn slow on a fresh install.

It’s also got a habit of crashing sometimes when I change my screen configuration or disable a monitor. My screens will just go blank and it’ll freeze up needing a restart to come back to life. When being shut down it's also very slow.

MiniToolBox dump—with a shutdown recently occurring—can [be found here](http://pastebin.com/tj6Gp3TE) and the specs are as follows:

- Intel 5960X Extreme 8-core 3.00GHz (Haswell-E) Socket LGA2011-V3 Processor - Retail (BX80648I75960X)
- 2 x Inno3D GeForce GTX 980 "iChill Herculez X4 Air Boss Ultra" 4096MB GDDR5 PCI-Express Graphics Card (C98U-1SDN-M5DNX)
- Asus Rampage V Extreme Intel X99 (Socket 2011) DDR EATX Motherboard
- 3 x - LG 24GM77 24" TRUE 144Hz Widescreen LED Monitor - Black w Flicker FREE Technology
- GeIL EVO Potenza 16GB (4x4GB) DDR4 PC4-21300C15 2666MHz Quad Channel Kit - Red (GPR416GB2666C15QC)
- SuperFlower Leadex Platinum 1000W Fully Modular "80 Plus Platinum" Power Supply - Black
- Corsair Hydro H100i High Performance Liquid CPU Cooler (CW-9060009-WW)
- Samsung 250GB SSD 840 EVO SATA 6Gb/s Basic - (MZ-7TE250BW)

Comment: If the SSD is the system disk then it shouldn't take more then 5 seconds to display the login screen.  The SSD should provide near instant boot times.  Do you have the SSD plugged into a SATA3 port?  Have you checked the performance of the SSD?  Have you made sure your using the current firmware for your SSD?

Comment: I'll double check the port. Firmware-wise I'll go online and have a look.

Additional logs after another issue when exiting Arma 2 (a video game) causing a shutdown moments ago: http://pastebin.com/8frzmQby

Comment: I also assumed your using a GPT partition, if you are not, then instantaneous boot times are unlikely even with a SSD although 40 seconds is still to long.

Comment: Partitions were managed/created by Windows during it's installation. Performance on my last PC was grseat, so I doubt the partition is of the wrong type.

Comment: Please verify.....If you are using MBR that could explain some of your slow performance problems.

Comment: First thing I would do is reset the BIOS on the motherboard to defaults. Assuming that your bios defaults to compatible settings (AHCI for SATA mode) The problems you are experiencing are nothing to do with your HDD configuration unless it is faulty.  - Also try running the system with one DDR4 stick to start with, and if ok then slowly add the others. Does the motherboard have onboard graphics? If so, remove your graphics card and use the onboard video to see if that eliminates the issue.

Comment: I agree with Johnny; I doubt it's the SSD or it's configuration. I'll see how the system runs as I just dismantled all the hardware and moved it into an easier to maintain case. No onboard graphics but will give the RAM idea a go.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I defaulted the settings in the BIOS menu if that's what you mean? I've heard cycling down the RAM speed might help too. I'll try loading the PC up with one stick tonight and see how it goes.

Comment: You need to clear the BIOS by using the jumper on the motherboard. Details of how to do this should be in the manual.

Comment: It's a brand new motherboard; is that really necessary yeah?